# Apache Server Request Timeout on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, apache

I already installed Apache Server and PHP on my Mac OS X, and they were working perfectly.

After upgrading my system, I found PHP compiler was no longer working, so I opened the file "httpd.conf" and cancelled the "#" before the very instruction.

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

But Apache Server could not find the document root (Library/Webserver/Documents) anymore, and a "127.0.0.1" requesting on Safari showed "Request Timeout(30s)". If it would work, there should be an "It works!"

```
http: error: Request timed out (30s).
```